# How to call a C# method for OnUndo in an Excel VSTO add-in?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm currently writing a VSTO add-in for Excel in C#, and am having trouble getting the undo functionality to work correctly.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, you are meant to use [`Application.OnUndo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194135.aspx) to register an undo callback.  However, it's not clear to me whether it's possible for the `Procedure` argument to refer to a C# method.

---

Ideally I would like to set the undo callback to an instance method, eg:

```
this.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
// ...
this.Application.OnUndo("Undo color change", "this.UndoTextColorChange");
```

Unfortunately, while this registers an undo, actually clicking 'undo' in Excel gives the error:

> Cannot run the macro 'this.UndoTextColorChange'.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

To me, this almost suggests that the `Procedure` argument has to be a VB macro (rather than a C# method).  However, it's also possible that I haven't been able to work out the fully-qualified procedure name to use in the `.OnUndo` call.

---

**Is it possible to have `Application.OnUndo` call a C# method?**  If so, what should I use as the argument for `Procedure`?  If not, how is undo functionality typically implemented in C# VSTO add-ins?

Comment: Unfortunately excel clears the undo stack if your code touches the object model. In essence you can have your code change something and then have users indo the changes you made. You might have to workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the `Procedure` argument of the `Application.OnUndo` has to be a VBA macro.

If you want the `Application.OnUndo` to call a C# method you will have to add a VBA macro to your workbook which will be triggered by the `Application.OnUndo`. Then the macro may call C# code from your VSTO add-in. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2019) is a good article describing how you can call VSTO code from VBA macro.

In order to inject a VBA macro into a workbook from your VSTO add-in you may [create an `.xlam` Excel Add-in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-macro-24a026ef-3145-4bf8-a5f2-2fc7889ff74a) and distribute it together with the VSTO Add-in (basically put it into the same folder or even embed it into VSTO Add-in itself as a resource file).

The `.xlam` Excel Add-in will be very simple and will contain a single function like below:

```
Sub UndoLastAction()
    Application.COMAddIns("YourVSTOLibraryName").UndoInVSTO
End Sub
```

When VSTO Add-in is started it can load `.xlam` add-in, so all the workbooks will have access to that VBA macro even if the workbook itself is not macro-enabled.

Below is a sample how you can load `.xlam` Excel Add-in from VSTO:

```
var undoManager = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns.Add("UndoManager.xlam", true);
undoManager.Installed = true;
```

Now, when you execute a certain modification via your VSTO Add-in and then would like to be able to Undo it you will have to call `Application.OnUndo`:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.OnUndo("Undo Last Operation", "UndoManager.xlam!UndoLastAction");
```

When `Application.OnUndo` is executed the Excel will allow user to click "Undo" button which will trigger `UndoLastAction` macro declared in the `.xlam` Add-in which will trigger `UndoInVSTO` function declared in `YourVSTOLibraryName` dll where you can do whatever you need to undo your last operation.